# Windows Server 2016 how to know if a service is going to start or not

Tags: windows-server-2016, service

I've a lot of service in Windows Server 2016.

Some of this service have a delayed start or a dependency.

I waited 20 minutes after server starts. There are 20 service still stopped.

Is there some tool or event a command to know if these service will start automatically or I must start them one by one?

Example:

I've a lot of Exchange's Service that sometimes not starts (about 25). Most of them has no dependencies. 
I've also some services depending on MS Exchange services, for example *POPBeamer* depends on *MS Exchange Transport Service*.
Now, the service "MS Transport Service" has no dependencies and automatic start. How can I check if it's starting or if it's went on error?

Why I need this?

Because I want to send "net start " command only if there are no pending starting. If some system is going to start , i don't won't to break the automatic system using a manual restart.

If "MS Transport Service" is marked has "restarting" or "pending" or "retrying to start", i don't want to send the command because some system is doing it for me in a better way (I suppose)

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far? Is something specifically not working? Which services are not working? Are all the dependency services started? Are there any errors in the event log for those services?

Comment: For instance, I've a lot of Exchange's Service that not starts (about 25). Most of them has no dependencies and some of them has automatic start and not delayed start. I must check log

Comment: Some may never start. Some are manually started by some controller in special circumstances or when certai nfeatures are used (but installed in the installer when the feature is installed). There is no way to know this. If a servie is set to start automatically, it will start automatically. It may decide to stop then.

Answer (score 0):

Services set to "automatic" will start or tried to start but failed. (Or in some rare cases stopped by itself.)

Do this to troubleshoot services which failed:

- Start event viewer (eventvwr.msc)
- Choose Windows Logs / System
- Right click "Filter Current Log"
- Select source "Service Control Manager"
- You will see all events relating to starting / stopping services and possible errors

Comment: I'm looking for a command (powershell or batch) or even a tools to do this. It's a very slow process to control event logger for 25 process, some of them 3 times because the system retry to start them, so at least 50 records

Comment: @DanieleLicitra to do what?

Comment: sorry, i was unclear. I don't want to send a lot of "net start <servicename>" command to the same service if this service is starting in some automatic way. So, if the service will start (something like "pending starting" or "retrying starts" status), I don't do the net start command. If the service is dead, has no activity and no scheduled start, i'll start it with the command